# db sendmail in SQL still showing rows affected after params turned off

Tags: sql

I'm sending results through an XML variable formatted with CSS and HTML in the body of an email.  I have everything exactly the way I want it and it's still showing the garbled text query at the bottom of the HTML email.  I have the @exclude_query_output turned off as well as SET NOCOUNT ON; in the actual @query paramater.

I've even tried to use NOCOUNT ON in the XML part of the SELECT statement and it's not working.  Everything else seems to be working great but the text query still shows at the bottom of the email.

I'm pasting partial code due to security but here is some of it:

```
DECLARE @xml NVARCHAR(MAX)
declare @variousothervariableshere, like @subject1
SET @subject1 = 'Send Statistics for '+ @datenamemonth + ' ' + @datenameyear

set nocount on;
SET @xml = CAST(( SELECT 
'left' as [td/@align], Task AS 'td','', 'center' as [td/@align],  NumofRecords AS 'td','' 
FROM [mytablehere] FOR XML PATH('tr'), ELEMENTS ) AS NVARCHAR(MAX))
set @HTMLBody = '<html><head>' 

            +  '<style>' 
            +  'th {border: solid blue 1px;padding-left:5px;padding-right:5px;padding-top:1px;padding-bottom:1px;font-size:11pt;} ' 
            +  'td {border: solid blue 1px;padding-left:5px;padding-right:5px;padding-top:1px;padding-bottom:1px;font-size:11pt;} ' 
            +  '</style>' 
            +  '</head>' 
            +  '<body>'
            + '<p>'
            +  '<table border="1">'
            +  '<tr>'
            +  '<th style="color:#fff000;">Num of Records</th>'
            +  '</tr>'
set @HTMLBody = @HTMLBody + @xml + '</table></body></html>'+'<font     face="Verdana" size="2" color="#333333"><p><br />Thanks,<br />My name here<p><p>'

EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
@exclude_query_output = 1,
@query_result_header = 0,
@profile_name = 'myprofilename',
@recipients = 'myemail@email.com',
@subject = @subject1,
@query = 'SET NOCOUNT ON; select * from [mytablehere]; SET NOCOUNT OFF;',
@body_format = 'HTML',
@body = @htmlbody

--end
```

Here is what is at the bottom of the email:

> Files Imported 0 Total Clean Records Imported 0 Emails Successfully Sent 0    Emails Queued or Retried to Send 0 Emails Failed 0 Number of Emails Exported for Manual Send due to No Data 0

This the exact text that is the HTML formatted table I have right above it.  It looks great in the table but I'm getting these results which is the exact query in text and it shouldn't be there because it's formatted in the table above.

Any suggestions would be awesome.  Also this is not the full HTML but you get the idea.

Comment: Remarkable! Sending an email in a database stored procedure! Have you heard of general purpose languages like ASP, Java, C#, PHP, Python, VB that can connect to databases and handle such procedures with try/catch exceptions, error handling, security, etc.? As information, SQL is a special-purpose language, limited in the context of database storage and querying. Leave business logic outside.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the @query parameter from the dbo.sp_send_dbmail call.

```
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
@exclude_query_output = 1,
@query_result_header = 0,
@profile_name = 'myprofilename',
@recipients = 'myemail@email.com',
@subject = @subject1,
@body_format = 'HTML',
@body = @htmlbody
```

Comment: Wow,  you know I took it off and it doesn't show up anymore.  I remember that it's already selecting from above using XML then it would be selecting it twice and sending the text query.  Thank you so much it worked!